# Group by issues with multiple columns

Tags: sql, group-by

I am having trouble making a query work. I am selecting 5 columns, using 3 to filter and 1 to count:

```
SELECT count(student), class_name, college, date, professor
WHERE *specific condition* = class_name 
AND *specific condition* = college 
AND *specific condition* = date 
GROUP BY professor, college
```

I keep getting an error that the other columns have to be grouped by or aggregated. I'm trying to get the total students per class per professor. I'm only selecting the other columns so I can filter out data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other columns are being selected for filtering purposes only, they do not need to be included in the `SELECT` statement.

The error is being caused because it cannot be decided which of the `date` and `class_name` entries the table has to show among the group.

Do try:

```
SELECT count(student), college, professor
--other lines equal
```

I don't see your `FROM` statement by the way.

Comment: Sorry, the From statement would just be "FROM table" all the data is in the same table. How can I filter columns without selecting them? For example I need the query to specifically not include some date and some class_name 's

Comment: Even if you do not select them, the filtering conditions would still work for the unselected columns.